# If $x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge -1$, and $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are all integers, find the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

[image]
as we can see, we are supposed to use stars and bars where n = 10 and r = 3. but what i dont understand is why we use stars and bars when stars and bars is supposed to be used in situations where we try to group 10 objects in 3 distinct groups, and the question is supposed to be asking us the number of ways we can get 3 integers that have a sum of 10. any help?

Comment: Check if you upload the correct picture

Comment: The question is badly formulated. "If $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq1$" is an assumption that implies that the $x_i$ are (fixed) values; the cannot then also serve as unknowns. It should have said "count the number of triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ of integers satisfying $x_i\geq-1$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $x _1+x_2+x_3=7$,

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that you have 10 balls and 2 sticks. The different ways you put these sticks between these balls divide your balls into three groups. The number of the balls in the first group is $x_1$ the number of the balls in the second group is $x_2$ and the number of the balls in the third one is $x_3$. I hope this would be clear.

Answer (score 0):

With new unknowns $x_i'=x_i+1\in\Bbb N$, you need to count the number of solutions to $x_1'+x_2'+x_3'=10$. Think of writing a solution to that last equation representing in the left hand side each $x_i$ by that many tally marks (say "$1$", so that $2+5+3$ becomes "$11{+}11111{+}111$"). Then you solution is represented by a sequence of $12$ symbols, $10$ of which are tally marks and the remaining $2$ are $+$ signs; since every arrangement of these symbols is allowed (possibly having no tally marks at all in a row to represent $0$), there are $\binom{12}{10}=\binom{12}2=66$ solutions.

Comment: You meant to write $\binom{12}{\color{red}{10}}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes, thanks for spotting that; corrected.